# wp_localize_script for inserting an image

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image

I'm having some trouble with wp_localize_script . There's plenty of questions about this already but I don't know how to implement them to this specific case. I made a jQuery file that includes an image after every div with a specific class. The jQuery itself is fine as I can change the image tag with a paragraph tag and then it shows up in my browser. Here's what I have in functions.php

```
function wpa_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'divider',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/divider.js',
    array('jquery'),
    null,
    true
);
$script_data = array(
    'image_path' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/'
);
wp_localize_script(
    'divider',
    'divider_data',
    $script_data
); } add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_scripts' );
```

And here's what I have in my .js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.contentpage').after('<img src=" '$script_data' + divider_placeholder.png">');   });
```

Can I anyone tell me what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Stef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `'divider_data.image_path'` instead of `$script_data` in your jQuery function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.contentpage').after('<img src="' + divider_data.image_path + 'divider_placeholder.png">');

});
```

Reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: Thank you! I'm quite new to Wordpress so my code may be an abomination of answers I found on the internet. Both answers are right :)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `$script_data` isn't in the right syntax in your js file as well as you don't access your predefined localized variable `divider_data`:

Instead of:
`$('.contentpage').after('<img src=" '$script_data' + divider_placeholder.png">');   });`

It should be:

```
$('.contentpage').after('<img src="' + divider_data.image_path + 'divider_placeholder.png">');   });
```